# Does Increasing $\dot{Q}_{\text{max}}$ with Insulation Thickness Prior to Reaching the Critical Radius Violate the Second Law of Thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have been studying heat transfer and came across the concept of the critical radius of insulation for cylindrical objects. According to the material I have, the critical radius of insulation is defined by the equation:

$$ r_{\text{critical}} = \frac{k}{h}$$

where $ k $ is the thermal conductivity of the insulating material, and $ h $ is the convective heat transfer coefficient.

However, there's an accompanying equation that equates the thermal resistance due to conduction to the thermal resistance due to convection, given by:

$$ \left(\frac{2\pi k L}{\ln(r_2/r_1)}\right) = \left(2\pi r_2 L h\right) $$

Solving this equation for $ r_1 $ gives:

$$ r_1 = r_2 e^{-k/(h r_2)} $$

This implies a specific relationship between $ r_1 $ and $ r_2 $ at the point of critical insulation thickness. However, a point of confusion arises from the observation that suggests an increase in the maximum heat transfer rate $ \dot{Q}_{\text{max}} $ as the insulation thickness increases, up until it reaches the critical radius.

This seems to suggest that there is a beneficial effect of increasing insulation thickness on heat transfer, which counterintuitively implies that adding insulation (up to a point) could technically increase the rate of heat loss. This observation appears to be in tension with the second law of thermodynamics, especially if we consider that increasing insulation is generally understood to reduce heat transfer.

Could this phenomenon of an increasing $ \dot{Q}_{\text{max}} $ for a non-equivalent $ r_1 $ and $ r_2 $ potentially violate the second law of thermodynamics? Or is there a misunderstanding on my part regarding the application of these principles in the scenario of critical insulation thickness?

Any clarifications on how the critical radius impacts heat transfer rates, especially in relation to the second law of thermodynamics, would be greatly appreciated.

**PS:** My real question here is whether the critical radius is correct and happens for a $ r_1 $ different than $ r_2 $. Has it been proved experimentally?

Comment: Does this concept make sense?  Adding a "small" layer of insulation to a cylinder increases the rate of heat transfer?  Are the proponents of this concept sellers of insulation?

Answer (score 0):

> This observation appears to be in tension with the second law of thermodynamics

Why? A hotter region is still heating a colder region.

> especially if we consider that increasing insulation is generally understood to reduce heat transfer.

That's a reasonable expectation for planar heat transfer: More planar insulation always acts as a barrier to heat transfer—lies "in the way" of the heat flux, essentially, for a given temperature difference—and that's that.

In radial (e.g., cylindrical or spherical) heat transfer, however, more insulation also provides more paths for heat flux, as adding insulation increases its lateral extent as well as its thickness.

To this we can add that small items are mostly surface area, in effect. That is, we generally expect surface effects to begin to dominate with decreasing size.

Since the lateral increase of applied insulation is a surface effect, we could broadly say that additional insulation around small objects gets wider more than it gets thicker. This greater width provides more access to surface heat transfer mechanisms such as convection around the entire insulated object.

> Has it been proved experimentally?

A search for `critical radius of insulation experimental` on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=critical+radius+of+insulation+experimental&btnG=) yields reports such as [this one](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/47240980/IJIRSTV2I12198-libre.pdf?1468494736=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DDesign_and_Fabrication_of_Experimental_S.pdf&Expires=1708545809&Signature=KxU0shPclD49mBiWPjNSnYgOon7GIw3KtR-fm0rOneU3NjbcmXxfmnP5pRBvd8kwThk6nh8TE1anOdstvAOv8dlf9gAzuVHJ5-wKIAkIYmRJrx8kVmXPPtV0PXOjS3wB6un9TX0xji6bDyUgsHGXZOqzlvN41GyWS9R-RhoKlbic8SxB1aUhOVR5uIZ-F0TwjPAsMb1E2fiZR6ACtM0CwMF6dNJZjdSeCz5WjQBDFBGRVOXA-ryONVHv%7E6N7Z0NX7ZOqj-0e85XlrMnI017DIMOukRls3VQNR0R7MX89LMvreygWNBEjg0jjD89-e1xh-QTSzX31UFWhI-1o7HWElA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA).

Answer (score 0):

For a cylindrical pipe additional insulation increases the thermal resistance of insulation. But it also decreases the convection resistance of the surface area due to the increase in the outer surface area.

Because of these opposite effects a critical radius of insulation is defined at the outer radius that provides the maximum rate of heat transfer.

For more information see: [https://www.sfu.ca/~mbahrami/ENSC%20388/Suggested%20Problems/Chapter%2010/P10-92.pdf](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Embahrami/ENSC%20388/Suggested%20Problems/Chapter%2010/P10-92.pdf)

Hope this helps.